# JS: Get Value from string

Tags: javascript, split

Im Looking for a way to search for a string inside a text and get the value behind it. Sorry, I am very bad at JS.

The text I'm using:

```
<label for="sample-group-15822160-0"><br>
<input name="sample-group-15822160" id="sample-group-15822160-0" value="option-1" numbercount="1" type="radio" checked="checked">Option 1</label>
```

What I need: 1

-> So just the value from the numbercount field inbetween the ".

What I tried:

```
var numhelper = sampleButtonObjects[index].outerHTML;
    var numhelperNum = ico1helper.split('numbercount="')[0].split('"')[1].trim();
                    var num = numhelperNum ;
```

What I received: sample-group-15822160-0 (the ID).

Can somebody please tell me, what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can you not target the input's `numbercount` attribute directly? Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why are you not just reading the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did all good except this tiny error

```
ico1helper.split('numbercount="')[0].split('"')[1].trim()
                                  ^             ^
```

The indices must be 1 & 0 in order to work

Comment: Thank you so much Pavitra. And the way you told me (you did all good"), made me feel good. So you're my hero for today :)

But, could you please explain me the difference, so that I would better understand in the future (I try to learn, not just to copy & paste)

Thank you :)

Comment: If you give me 15 minutes, I can visualise this for you :)

Comment: @ThomasB Go to these pages and run "Visualize Execution" button

Comment: *buggy code* http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=var%20text%20%3D%20%60%3Cinput%20name%3D%22sample-group-15822160%22%20id%3D%22sample-group-15822160-0%22%20value%3D%22option-1%22%20numbercount%3D%221%22%20type%3D%22radio%22%20checked%3D%22checked%22%3EOption%201%3C/label%3E%60%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text.split%28'numbercount%3D%22'%29%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text%5B0%5D%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text.split%28'%22'%29%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text%5B1%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: *working code* http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=var%20text%20%3D%20%60%3Cinput%20name%3D%22sample-group-15822160%22%20id%3D%22sample-group-15822160-0%22%20value%3D%22option-1%22%20numbercount%3D%221%22%20type%3D%22radio%22%20checked%3D%22checked%22%3EOption%201%3C/label%3E%60%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text.split%28'numbercount%3D%22'%29%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text%5B1%5D%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text.split%28'%22'%29%0A%0Atext%20%3D%20text%5B0%5D&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: You're awesome Pavitra. Thank you so much and have a great day!